# Is General Relativity compatible with Mach's Principle?

Tags: general-relativity, inertial-frames, machs-principle

Einstein proposed what he called [Mach's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle). For the purposes of this question can we define Mach's Principle as being that e.g. if a bucket suspended by a rope contains water riding up on the sides, that phenomenon could be accounted for by (a) regarding the bucket and water as rotating, but could also be accounted for by (b) regarding the bucket and water being stationary (and the remainder of the masses in the universe rotating around it), and there is no detectable phenomenon which proves or could prove that (a) is correct and (b) incorrect, or vice versa. I.E. there is no such thing as "absolute" rotation - it is (like velocity) relative.

Einstein later proposed General Relativity. It is often said that GR is "not Machian" or "not very Machian".

My question is: Is GR incompatible with Mach's Principle (as defined above) - i.e. If GR is true does that make it logically impossible for Mach's Principle to also be true?

Or, to put it another way, when people say that GR is "not Machian" or "not very Machian" do they simply mean that GR does not *require* Mach's Principle to be true (but equally does not prove it to be untrue)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mach's principle was one of the motivations for Einstein to develop General Relativity.  However when it was completed, it didn't incorporate Mach's principle and apparently later on Einstein doubted Mach's principle.

Your last sentence seems to summarise it well

> GR does not require Mach's Principle to be true (but equally does not prove it to be untrue)

Section 1.3 of [Mach's Priciple](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0407078.pdf) has the title 'Mach's principle and General Relativity' and is worth a read.

Comment: In the very interesting link you provide it says "The conflict between general relativity and Machian dragging can be clearly seen in the gravitomagnetic clock effect. Consider
a circular equatorial geodesic orbit about a central rotating mass and imagine two
free test clocks on this orbit moving in opposite directions. According to general
relativity, the clock in prograde motion moves slower and takes longer than the clock
in retrograde motion to complete the orbit." The implication seems to be that the  effect would not be expected by MP but the reason for implying this is not explained

Comment: @Nemo yes, it also says that "inertial forces having gravitational origin" is probably ruled out by General Relativity, - then it depends what version of Mach's principle is being considered, it might still be ok for a reference frame to be provided by the distant stars.

Answer (score 9):

First off: as you mention: what is known as 'Mach's principle' was proposed by Einstein. (Also: Mach's austere philosophy of science is opposed to such a grand statement.) Einstein coined the name 'Mach's principle'. I want to emphasize that it was proposed by Einstein so I call it 'Einstein's Mach's principle.

Historians of physics describe the following:

Around 1915 Einstein was convinced that Einstein's Mach's principle is fundamental to GR.

Among the logical implications of the form of Einstein's Mach's principle that Einstein used was that in order for spacetime to exist there must be distribution of matter/energy in it.

A couple of years later the dutch astronomer Willem de Sitter found a solution to the Einstein Field Equations that describes a Universe with no matter in it.

This result was opposite to Einstein's expectation. Historians of physics describe that for quite a while Einstein tried hard to show that there was some mathematical error. Einstein worked to show that the de Sitter solution was actually invalid. But in the end Einstein had to admit that the de Sitter solution was in fact valid.

Historians of science describe that after that Einstein ceased to mention Einstein's Mach's Principle in articles about GR.

In 1954, in a letter written in reply to a specific question Einstein wrote: "Von dem Machschen Prinzip sollte man eigentlich überhaupt nicht mehr sprechen." (We shouldn't talk about Mach's principle anymore, really.)
(Written communication between Einstein and Felix Pirani)

Main source for this information:
Michel Jansen, 2008, [Einstein's Quest for General Relativity, 1907-1920](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/4377/)

Additional reading:
John Norton, [Mach's principle before Einstein](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Ejdnorton/papers/MachPrinciple.pdf)

My understanding is that there are multiple versions of "Mach's principle" in circulation. It seems to me that in order to begin to assess the question first the multiple versions of the principle would need to be categorized.

**Einstein's version**

I don't know which version the principle was in Einstein's thoughts, but it is interesting to see that Einstein's version was rendered untenable by the fact that de Sitter's solution is valid.

Decades later Johh Wheeler coined the phrase: "Curved spacetime is telling inertial mass how to move, inertial mass is telling spacetime how to curve." (Or words to that effect.) It appears to me that Einstein held to view where inertial mass is not only telling spacetime how to curve, but that in order for the *Einstein Field* to exist presence of *inertial mass* is necessary. (I use the expression 'Einstein Field' here as meaning: that which is described by the *Einstein Field equations*. The Einstein Field equations describe Einstein spacetime.)

It would appear that Einstein held a view (prior to being confronted by the de Sitter solution) that the existence of spacetime and inertial-mass-in-spacetime is fundamentally co-dependent. It would appear that this concept of co-dependency was sufficient to satisfy the version of Einstein's Mach's principle that Einstein used.

Comment: As you rightly say there are a large number of different (but loosely connected) definitions of "Mach's Principle". In order to avoid that problem my question defines what I mean by MP (for the purposes of the question). I can see that Einstein hoped that his work on GR would prove Mach's Principle (or one formulation of Mach's Principle) and that the discovery that his equations worked in empty space was in that regard a setback. But my question is not so much about whether GR proves MP (as I have defined it) but rather whether or not GR positively disproves MP (as I have defined it)..

Comment: @Nemo Please note: What de Sitter discovered was not: 'the Einstein field equations work in empty space'. It was: there is a solution to the Einstein field equations that describes a space without any matter in it. That is an essential distinction. Also: abilty to appreciate that distinction is a must.

Comment: Noted. The problem is the word limit on comments: hence the shorthand.

Comment: @Nemo OK. Shorthand. In retrospect: the following is equal length: 'the discovery of the de Sitter solution was in that regard a setback'.  Comment sections sometimes become cluttered. To declutter I will soon remove these latest comments, so that only relevant comment remains

Answer (score 1):

The question of Mach's principle already arises at the level of special relativity.

I recommend a very interesting book on the subject : "relativity Matters" J Rafelski, Springer.

I can't do better than quote this book (p 439):

> This was the situation when about 150 years ago Ernst Mach returned to
> the question raised by Newton. Mach proposed the ‘Universe at rest’
> defined by the fixed stars, to be Newton’s absolute space. Adapting
> these ideas to the post-relativity context of this book we would say
> that we always measure acceleration against any know inertial frame,
> and the fixed star frame is a suitable inertial reference frame.
> Therefore choice of a preferred inertial frame such as that proposed
> by Mach is not in conflict with special relativity. ….

> The choice of an inertial frame made by Mach makes good sense for the merry-go-round
> experiment in space, far from anything. By looking at starlight we can
> determine who is rotating and who is not. Now the entire universe
> dictates the answer to who is accelerated. However, this also prompts
> us to reflect a question: “how does the water bucket know about the
> universal inertial frame?” Especially in a book where we often check
> if casual sequence of events is guaranteed, it seems doubtful that
> this information is transferred from distant locations of fixed stars,
> ‘informing’ the water bucket to curve its surface. This information
> about who or what is accelerated has to be available locally.  …..

> One can see the situation as follow: the same quantum vacuum state
> properties that assure quark confinement, and predominantly define the
> inertial mass of matter, also define at a very microscopical scale the
> inertial frame of reference.

Comment: My question is about the logical compatibility (or otherwise) or GR and a particular definition of MP.

Comment: I think that SR and GR are related. And the author's remark about the role of the quantum vacuum in the definition of an inertial referential raises questions for general relativity.

Comment: (I am occasionally amused by the typo of "casual order of events" for "causal..." ... Sorry. :)