# What shape would the orbit of a floating object inside a 'massive' planet be according to Newton?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, orbital-motion, centripetal-force

Imagine a hypothetical spherical planet with a massive core but which is somehow internally traversable without friction (f.i. due to a tunnel or a superfluid core). What shape would the orbit of a free falling object inside it be according to Newton, traversing such tunnel that happens to be identical to its trajectory, or through the frictionless superfluid? We know outside of the planet a moon would have an elliptical orbit according to Kepler, but what shape would the orbit of a moon *inside* this hypothetical planet be?

Imagine the thought experiment of Newtons cannonball , but then shot from somewhere midway the planet instead of on the surface of the planet. And without escape velocity for this matter.

The reason I ask for such a mental stretch is because in the Principia, Newton gives an example to explain the brachistochrone curve being a cycloid using the attractive force *inside* a hollow planet (prop. 49 theorem 17). In prop. 52 cor. 1 he uses the case of a Tusi couple (special case of the cycloid) inside the hollow planet, assuming a linear attractive force instead of the inverse square law. However in reality (for as far as I understand) it turns out the linear attractive force is only the case inside a *massive* planet.

Hence the case of my current hypothetical planet. The Tusi couple resembles a harmonic oscillator (which it should with a linear attractive force) when it equals half the diameter of the planet. However if you extend its reach by making it a trochoid, it will create elliptical orbits surrounding the planet. My quest is to discover if the smaller trochoid will resemble the orbit of a free falling object inside the planet as well, or not.

Thus, will that orbit under the influence of the linear attractive force inside the massive planet be elliptical, circular, or otherwise?

Comment: How does a mass move through a gas without friction (aka drag)?

Comment: Is the gaseous core spherically symmetric?

Comment: You probably need to understand [the shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) but the conditions you state are not physically realistic.

Comment: I should mention [worldbuilding.se] where they often discuss artificial (and unphysical) world systems and I know the hollow planet idea has multiple posts.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added some background context for the reason to this impossible hypothetical situation, also trying to make it a little more 'possible' for its purpose

Comment: This is an excellent question and my only doubt is whether it mightn’t be better suited to Maths rather than Physics. Physicists either assume that gravity is constant (as when they say that the path of a projectile is a parabola rather than the top of an ellipse) or $\frac1{r^2}$. As you have seen, any other power of $r$ makes them nervous.

Comment: Thanks I posted it at the math section as well now

Answer (score 2):

I will simplify the setup as follows:
If you have a spherical gravitating body of uniform density: what shape would an internal conduit have to be such that an object can move through that conduit in orbital motion, consistent with the gravitational potential of that gravitating body.

we have the following: the gravitational potential inside a sphere of uniform density is according to Hooke's law.

From the physics website by Richard Fitzpatrick: [Potential Due to a Uniform Sphere](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newton/node107.html)

At the end of that page Fitzpatrick points out:

> According to Equation (897), the gravitational potential inside a uniform sphere is quadratic in $r$. This implies that if a narrow shaft were drilled though the center of the sphere then a test mass, $m$, moving in this shaft would experience a gravitational force acting toward the center which scales linearly in $r$. In fact, the force in question is given by $f_r = -m\,\partial\Phi/\partial r = -(G\,m\,M/a^3)\,r$. It follows that a test mass dropped into the shaft executes simple harmonic motion about the center of the sphere [...]

In the case of orbital motion under the influence of an attracting force according to Hooke's law we can think of orbital motion as a superposition of two harmonic oscillations, at 90 degrees to each other.

So the shape of the conduit has to be in the form of an ellipse, with geometric center of that ellipse at the center of attraction. *Any* ellipse with the geometric center at the center of attraction will do; all those are solutions to the equation of (orbital) motion.

It is quite remarkable that two different force laws both give rise to orbital motion in the shape of an ellipse, but in a different way.

As we know: in the case of an inverse square law of attraction one *focus* of the ellipse is at the center of attraction.

In the case of orbital motion subject to Hooke's law: the *geometric center* of the ellipse coincides with the center of attraction.

Interestingly, it is possible to create a fairly simple setup that is a good approximation of orbital motion in a quadratic potential.

There is an instance of that as part of the lab exercises of the Meteorology course at MIT: [Construction of parabolic turntable](http://marshallplumb.mit.edu/experiments/gfd-iv-parabolic-table)

There is a shallow dish, diameter about 1 meter, on a driven turntable, the rotation rate is about 10 revolutions per minute.

With the dish rotating a resin is poured out. Since the resin is a fluid it becomes distributed such that in the final state there is no more opportunity to dissipate energy. In the final state the slope of the surface provides the required centripetal force, which implies that the derivative of the slope with respect to radial distance is a linear function of radial distance. Accordingly the cross section of the surface is in the shape of a parabola, hence the name *parabolic turntable*.

The resin is allowed to set, and then sanded to a smooth finish. For a demonstration with very little friction small disks consisting of [dry ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_ice) are used. The evaporating carbondioxide reduces friction to a minimum.

The rotating setup is equipped with a video camera co-linear with the axis of rotation, looking down onto the rotating platform, co-rotating with the platform.

The following animation shows a schematic representation of the motion pattern that arises in a quadratic potential:

[image: Motion in a quadratic potential]

The arrow represents that centripetal force that arises from the slope of the surface.

To help keep track of the motion the rim of the circular platform is divided in 4 quadrants. The animation on the right shows what view is as seen from a co-rotating point of view.

Answer (score -2):

A circular orbit or an elliptical orbit of a non-propulsive object around a planet only exists because there is a gravitational potential of the more distant masses of the universe.  The gravitational potential of a planet is opposed to the potential of the rest of the universe. A planet existing alone in space will inevitably accelerate an object, whether stationary or in orbit, towards itself.

Allowing for your hollow planet, the surrounding masses of the universe should be taken into account. Since both gravitational potentials - that of the rest of the universe and that of the hollow planet - now add up, your object will immediately fall in a parabola or directly vertically upwards onto the inner surface.

Comment: [Is General Relativity compatible with Mach's Principle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/660664/46708)