# How to explain the Newton bucket in terms of general relativity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity

I know that the water curves as the bucket rotates. Could someone explain the curve of the water with arguments borrowed from general relativity?

Comment: Why would GR explain the water curvature? Are you thinking it might explain Mach's principle?

Comment: I think this question might be a possible duplicate of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/660656/is-general-relativity-compatible-with-machs-principle)

Comment: Are you asking to explain why water makes a parabola? or the relation between the bucket argument and reference frames in general relativity?

Comment: @  Mauricio both if you know something about please write

Comment: @Larsaseeidaklaxtarsa the two are very different in nature. One ask how to make the mathematical derivation of the surface of the liquid in a rotating frame using GR (this might be very hard). The other is a discussion of Mach principle and there are answers to that already https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/660656/is-general-relativity-compatible-with-machs-principle